# Wrap and No-Wrap Paragraphs next to Image

Tags: css, image, word-wrap

I have one image which is floated left. It will have two pieces of content next to it - the first one will be "non-wrapping" text. The second bit of content, below the "non-wrapping" content, should be "wrapping" text and go back under the image. What is the best practice to achieve this result?

Comment: Please post some code.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
float:left;
```

On the non-wrapping text

Check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wX4xh/1/)** I created for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attrubute:

```
align="left"
<img id="imgAuthor" src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" align="left">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JvDys/